# I need form validation that can change the DIV wrap properties. Anyone?

Tags: javascript, validation

I need form validation that can change the DIV wrap properties. Anyone?

```
 <div id="r1" class="shp">
 <input class="textQ" style="width: 82px;" title="Zip Code"> 
 </div>
```

I need to change #r1 properties if thee is an error.  Need help.

Comment: any particular programming language?

Comment: I prefer jquery.  I have a form with the names, emails, requiring the min, etc...  I need to change the CSS properties of the DIV wraps that hold the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using the jQuery validation plugin, in my opinion.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

It's very flexible and powerful.